# Firestore snapshot - are dynamic queries possible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two listeners - one for the user's `profile` and one for the `rooms` the user is in; the uids of the `rooms` are stored in an array on the `profile`, i.e. the query for the second listener depends on data from the first.

It looks like this (simplified):

```js
// profile listener
onSnapshot(profileRef, (snapshot) => setProfile(snapshot.doc.data())

// rooms listener
const roomsQuery = query(
  collection(db, "rooms")
  where("uid", "in", profile.roomsList)
)
onSnapshot(roomsQuery, (snapshot) => setRooms(snapshot.docs)
```

When the user is added to a new `room`, the `profile` updates with the new `roomsList`. But the `rooms` snapshot doesn't update - presumably because the query can't be updated dynamically.

#### Question

So, is there a way of updating the listener's query (i.e. keeping the same listener), or do I have to unsubscribe from the existing listener and re-subscribe with the new query every time `profile` is updated?

##### Versions

Using the new V9 of the Javascript sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore queries are immutable, so there's no way to change the condition once the query has been created. You'll indeed have to attach a listener to a new query to get  the updates `roomsList`. If you [enable offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) though, the overlapping documents between the queries will be read from the local cache.

Also see: [How to constantly update query for Firebase Realtime Database with LiveData and ViewModel in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752533/how-to-constantly-update-query-for-firebase-realtime-database-with-livedata-and/72753982#72753982)